# Poisson's distribution , Frustration solitaire

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I m not sure how to solve this question from Introduction to Probability & statistics for scientists and engineers,Sheldon M. Ross.
Need help.

The game of frustration solitaire is played by turning the cards of a randomly
shuffled deck of 52 playing cards over one at a time. Before you turn over the
first card, say ace; before you turn over the second card, say two, before you turn
over the third card, say three. Continue in this manner (saying ace again before turning over the fourteenth card, and so on). You lose if you ever turn over a card
that matches what you have just said. Use the Poisson paradigm to approximate
the probability of winning. (The actual probability is .01623.)

Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: If we make a couple of wrong (but not very wrong) assumptions we get $e^{-52/13}$.

Comment: Still couldn't what the approximation could be ?
Please help .

Comment: Assume (incorrectly) independence. So we shuffle after each turn. Then the number of hits has binomial distribution, $n=52$, probability of a hit on any trial equal to $1/13$. The Binomial distribution with $n$ "large", $p$ small, $np$ modest is well approximated by the Poisson with parameter $\lambda=np$. Here $np=4$, and the probability that a Poisson with parameter $4$ takes the value $0$ is $e^{-4}$.

Comment: Is there any reason why we could take the approximation of independence ?

Comment: I could say it makes life easier.  And informally the dependence is weak. The general idea is often used to make ballpark estimates.

Comment: Note by the way the following absolutely accurate result. Let $X$ be the number of "hits."  Then the mean of $X$ is exactly $4$.  Of course that does not imply $X$ is roughly *Poisson* with mean $4$. But it is.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Binomial is easy enough to compute and note that it is more accurate than Poisson. See figure in my Answer.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo: Agreed. I used Poisson rather than Binomial after the independence simplification in order to stay within the Poisson spirit that the question seemed to be asking for.  In an Answer rather than comment, I would have listed the assumptions that lead formally to the Poisson, and bypassed the Binomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Right. My (answer-format) Comment started from my attempt to explore OP's skepticism about Poisson assumptions. A perfectly reasonable decision by Ross to give this Poisson exercise. Only as I tinkered did I finally realize how much better binomial fits true model. Incidentally, any idea how to get exact analytical solution.?Doubt Ross got exact probability by simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Comment.

It is difficult to simulate small probabilities with good accuracy.
Nevertheless, a simulation of a million plays of this game gives
just good enough results to distinguish between the approximate
answer $e^{-4} \approx 0.018$ and the exact answer $\approx 0.016.$
[The simulation also shows the number of 'hits' (matches between
what is called and what is revealed), assuming the game is
continued until the deck is exhausted. Four is the average
number of hits; similar to the Poisson as suggested by @AndreNicholas; also, the most likely number.]

```
 m = 10^6;  call = rep(1:13, times=4);  hit = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   shuf = sample(call, 52)
   hit[i] = sum(call == shuf) }
 mean(hit == 0)
 ## 0.016293    # approx of actual answer P(no hits)
 mean(hit)
 ## 4.000411    # expected number of hits.
 exp(-4)   
 ##  0.01831564 # Poisson approximation

 round(table(hit)/m, 4)  # approx dist'n of hits
 ## hit
 ##      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8 
 ## 0.0163 0.0691 0.1443 0.1977 0.2011 0.1617 0.1051 0.0586 0.0280 
 ##      9     10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17 
 ## 0.0118 0.0043 0.0014 0.0004 0.0001 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
```

The figure below shows the simulated distribution of hits (histogram bars) along with the PDF (open red circles) of the approximating $Pois(4)$ and the PDF (solid blue dots) of $Binom(52, 1/13).$
This problem is fine as an exercise in using the Poisson approximation, but the binomial is more accurate and it is easy
enough to compute $(12/13)^{52} =  0.01557$, more accurate
than $e^{-4} = 0.01832.$
Only the values at 0 are directly relevant to the Question.

[image]

Comment: Because it takes many thousands of simulated games to begin to distinguish between 0.018 and 0.016, the Poisson approximation is plenty good for practical purposes. Who is going to play even 10,000 games? For recreational purposes, knowing the name 'frustration solitaire' indicates a very low chance of winning is probably enough. If you're gambling at anywhere near fair odds it will be a long time until you know whether odds are slightly favorable or slightly unfavorable.